# PHP: how get answer from a UDP server

Tags: php, sockets

I'm tryng to implement this discovery message for Yeelight lamp (link to manual: http://www.yeelight.com/download/Yeelight_Inter-Operation_Spec.pdf)

```
The searching message generated by 3rd device should follow below format and rules and
being sent to multi-cast address 239.255.255.250:1982 over UDP.
-------------------------------------------------------------
M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1
HOST: 239.255.255.250:1982
MAN: "ssdp:discover"
ST: wifi_bulb
-------------------------------------------------------------
1. The start line must be "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1" without any leading LWP.
2. "HOST" header is optional, if it's present, the value should be "239.255.255.250:1982".
3. "MAN" header is required. The value for "MAN" header must be "ssdp:discover",
double quotes included.
4. "ST" header is required. The value for "ST" header must be "wifi_bulb".
5. The headers are case-insensitive while the start line and all the header values are case
sensitive. Each line should be terminated by "\r\n".
```

I admit: I'm not able to work with socket, so I did try and failed (no answer, on var dump only "int(116)").

```
$discover_message = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\n
        HOST: 239.255.255.250:1982\r\n
        MAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\n
        ST: wifi_bulb\r\n";

        $socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Cannot create a socket");
        socket_connect($socket,'239.255.255.250','1982') or die("Couldnot connect to socket");
        $ret = socket_sendto($socket,$discover_message,strlen($discover_message),0,'239.255.255.250','1982');
        socket_set_nonblock($socket);
        var_dump($ret);
```

I did try also add

```
$socket=socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP) or die("Cannot create a socket");
        socket_connect($socket,'239.255.255.250','1982') or die("Couldnot connect to socket");
        $ret = socket_sendto($socket,$discover_message,strlen($discover_message),0,'239.255.255.250','1982');
        socket_set_nonblock($socket);
        var_dump($ret);
        $sec = 0;
        $usec = $sec === null ? null : (($sec - floor($sec)) * 1000000);
        $r = array($socket);
        while (socket_select($r, $x, $x, $sec, $usec)) {
            $data = socket_read($socket, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ);
            var_dump($data);
        }
```

(reading how implemented on another github project, this one uses a packagist socket that wrapper socket itself)

but I get the `int(116)` again.

The answer need to be (as stated by manual)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
Date:
Ext:
Location: yeelight://192.168.1.239:55443
Server: POSIX UPnP/1.0 YGLC/1
id: 0x000000000015243f
model: color
fw_ver: 18
support: get_prop set_default set_power toggle set_bright start_cf stop_cf set_scene
cron_add cron_get cron_del set_ct_abx set_rgb 

power: on
bright: 100
color_mode: 2
ct: 4000
rgb: 16711680
hue: 100
sat: 35
name: my_bulb
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

How get my list of lamp, as stated on the manual?

Thank you

Comment: Do you wait for an answer? It looks like both `$sec` and `$usec` are 0, so `socket_select()` returns immediately. As the call directly follows the `socket_sendto()` with no `sleep()` in between, the answer might not be there yet,

Comment: @KarstenKoop Yes, I need an answer, as per manual (copy and paste the demo answer from manual itself). So, do I need to introduce a sleep? Or how to edit the code? Thank you in advance

Comment: Well, as I said, you immediately try to read the answer with a timeout of zero. Sending data over the network takes somewhere around one millisecond, so you have to insert a timeout. Why don't you just pass 1 second as a timeout to `socket_select()` and see what happens? Also, try using Wireshark to see the network traffic.

Comment: I will try to add the timeout. Based on my question, on docs, and my code, seems right my code to get that answer, other than timeout?